# Why is it only IE that has conditional comments?

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-comments

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Are there any other uses of conditional comments i'm missing or is it only IE that gets these?

Also, why is only IE that gets these?

Answer (score 3):

You're right; only IE has this feature.

It is a feature that Microsoft invented for IE back in the days of the browser wars. It was never approved as a standard and no other browser maker ever implemented it.

They implemented it as part of a suite of features aimed at making life easier for IE-only developers so they could work out which IE version they were working in. This was necessary because IE (in common with other browsers at the time) was developing non-standard features and there were often extremely significant changes from one version to the next.

So it was intended for IE developers, but in fact it's ended up working to the opposite effect, as it is now commonly used by cross-browser developers as a way of hacking their site to make it work with older versions of IE.

In truth, it is probably a good thing that none of the other browser makers ever implemented it, because although it does indeed make it dead easy to know what version of the browser you're in, browser/version detection is generally considered to be poor practice.

Current thinking favours **feature detection** instead of browser/version detection. For this you use a tool such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to determine the features that the user's browser supports, which gives you much finer grained control over how to deal with older browsers.

However, in the case of older versions of IE, the browser is so badly incompatible with some standards that this is sometimes not sufficient, and one does need to check for the browser and version in this specific case. Given this, it is a blessing that the conditional comment feature is available. And given that no other browser has such issues, it is probably just as much of a blessing that they don't support conditional comments.

In an ideal world, no-body would still be using such old versions of IE that require this kind of hack. But they are, and we need to support them, so for those few cases where you can't do it with feature detection, conditional comments are the way to go.

**[EDIT]**
This is an old answer, but it is worth resurecting because as of IE10, conditional comments are no longer supported. IE10 is a much *much* better browser than its predecessors, and Microsoft have been actively pushing to make it as modern and standards-compliant as possible. Removing the conditional comments feature is part of that push. Conditional comments remain in place for older versions of course, and the arguments above for and against using them remain, but for IE10 and future versions going forward, the option of conditional comments to deal with browser issues is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft implemented these so developers could take advantage of enhanced features of newer browsers. But indeed, like answered above, they are now more used to make sure code that works in different browsers also work in IE.

Full story:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need conditional comments to get help the IE to render your page. Otherwise most pages would not show correctly in IE (because of not handling defaults correctly).

Comment: To be fair the other vendors also need some hand tweaking to get stuff working, but it's definetly less of an issue.